# I would like to know how to use the wx.gridsizer to set the text background setting to one color

Tags: wxpython

There are four color backgrounds attached.
I set the background using wx.gridsizer so background applies only to text size. I would like to have a one line color line as an attached image. How do I do this?

Must be sorted by wx.gridsizer.

```
import wx
class test(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self):
      wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
      main = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.DEFAULT)

      a=wx.StaticText(main, label='111111111')
      a.SetBackgroundColour('red')
      b=wx.StaticText(main, label='222222222')
      b.SetBackgroundColour('blue')
      c=wx.StaticText(main, label='333333333')
      c.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
      d=wx.StaticText(main, label='444444444')
      d.SetBackgroundColour('cyan')

      sizer = wx.GridSizer(0,4,10,10)
      sizers = (a,b,c,d)

      for i in sizers:
         sizer.Add(i, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 1)
      vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
      vbox.Add(sizer, wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
      main.SetSizer(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = test()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sizers, size, they don't have a method to set the background colour.
Your issue is that you are adding a `horizontal gap` of 10 between the items in the sizer `sizer = wx.GridSizer(0,4,10,10)`.
Change that to `sizer = wx.GridSizer(0,4,10,0)`
Some of the platforms supported by wxPython (most notably GTK), do not consider wx.StaticText as a separate widget; instead, the label is just drawn directly on its parent window.  These platforms do not allow the developer to change the widgets background colour.
Using **GenStaticText** will overcome all the problems described above, as it is a generic widget and a real window on its own.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.stattext as ST
class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        main = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        a=ST.GenStaticText(main, label='111111111', size=(100,-1))
        b=ST.GenStaticText(main, label='222222222', size=(100,-1))
        c=ST.GenStaticText(main, label='3333', size=(100,-1))
        d=ST.GenStaticText(main, label='444444444', size=(100,-1))
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(0,4,10,0)
        sizers = (a,b,c,d)
        for i in sizers:
            i.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
            sizer.Add(i, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(sizer, wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        main.SetSizer(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = test()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that I have given each statictext a `size` this ensures that the length of the text does not override the decisions the sizer makes and keeps things consistent.

[image]

Comment: I use `GenStaticText` so the background is transparent in Windows too !? Thank you for being one of the features I wanted the most.